# How to pass arguments to selenium from autoit script

Tags: automated-testing, java, selenium-webdriver

Autoit has an order value, which I want to pass it to the database as an argument to get table contents of that order id.

I tried passing from *command-line*, but I don't want the arguments to get passed from the command line. I am using Selenium web driver with Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could store them in an .INI file and read this during your tests in your @BeforeClass using:

```
Preferences args = new IniFile(new File(fname));
```

Since my tests are coming from HP ALM and the `testng-suite.xml` is generated automatically, I simply added my arguments as parameters into the XML.
You could also use AutoIt to add the lines into your `testng-suite.xml`

```
<suite verbose="-1" name="TestAutomationTest.MBC-POS-Suite" configfailurepolicy="skip" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="selenium.url" value="https://dfs.com" />
```

You can access them then in your test method, each parameter is one argument in your test method:

```
@Test
@Parameters({"selenium.url", "timeOut.msec"})
public void testMethod(String url, int timeout)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code snippet to pass arguments to autoit script, which then can be used in Selenium for uploading a file where we can pass the file path dynamically.

```
ControlFocus("File Upload", "", "Edit1")
ControlSetText("File Upload", "", "Edit1", $CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("File Upload", "" , "Button1")
```

Here, `CmdLine[1]` is the argument that we are passing dynamically.